# How change top navigation menu from ol to ul?

Tags: layout, theme, topmenu

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 and this is generating the menu as follow:

```
<ol class="nav-primary">
  <li  class="level0 nav-1 first level-top">
   <a href="">Item 1</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I need to change the root element of nav from  (ordered list) to  (unordered list). I checked the **app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Navigation.php** but did not find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/code/design/frontend/namesapce/theme/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml**

you can change here `<ol>` to `<ul>`. Only these `<li></li>` element are generate from `app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Navigation.php`

```
<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>
```